# Passing a member function of a class as pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Well this might be not the best solution to my problem so I will explain what I want to do.

I want to create a function which is a generic version of other classes (an interface in java way of seeing it). And then create a specialization of each class.

Later I want to create a vector of the generic class but each member of the vector is in reallity a casted member of the each specialized class. So when I call a function of each class in the vector call a diffrent function.

I tryied to do this using only inherence but, when I call the function of the vector call the implementation of the father and not it specialization.

I don't wnat to cast each member of the vector to call the right function because the hole point of doing this is to generalize a problem in the code. I mean make a dynamic behavor.

I also tryied to use pointers so the specialized class assign it function to a function pointer which is the one will be call. But this was not allowed because the pointer is `namespace::classgeneralization::(int)(*f)();` and the function I want to point is `namespace::classgeneralization::classspecialization::int f()();` so it do not compile.

I could may implemente the function out of the class and then point it in the class, but this is really ofuscate code I think. I also tryed to see if I could use a pointer to a lamda function but this is not posible at least in VS2010 as far I could research.

Maybe the hole perspective of solving the problem is wrong, and there is a way to do this properly and less ofuscate as I am trying. In any case I am open to other perspectives, so long I achive a vector of classes which each element is a different class with thiferent implementations of functions.

Comment: Reading your description, I think you should read about [object slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

Comment: Also, reading about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) might be useful. Though I'm not sure it's fully supported in VS2010.

Comment: I will like to know why the question was downgraded. If is because my poor english I am sorry but I find it unfair for not natives english speakers

Comment: VS2010 most certainly does support `std::function`

Comment: I check I made I quick test and didn't work, sorry.

Comment: @user223506 Then your test is wrong or your copy of VS2010 is incomplete.

Comment: my test was wrong. Sorry about it. Thanks to @JoachimPileborg  and Captain Obvlious. I think this will solve the problem

Comment: @user223506 Now that your `std::function` test is working take a look at `std::bind`. It will come in handy as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to understand your question, but it sounds to me that you are trying to achieve polymorphism in a very cumbersome way. Maybe the following code helps:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class MyInterface
{
public:
   virtual void f() { std::cout << "MyInterface::f() called" << std::endl; }
};

class A : public MyInterface 
{
public:
   virtual void f() { std::cout << "A::f() called" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public MyInterface 
{
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<MyInterface*> objects;
   objects.push_back(new A);
   objects.push_back(new B);

   objects[0]->f();
   objects[1]->f();

   return 0;
}
```

This will output:

```
A::f() called
MyInterface::f() called
```

Comment: I was trying to do somthing like this, but without creating pointers. Is posible to do this behavor without pointers, declare the objects and not as pointers to objects?

Comment: No, as Joachim Pileborg mentioned in a comment to your question, using std::vector<MyInterface> will result in slicing. See Joachims link for more information. I would also advise you to gain some more insight of values, references and pointers in C++.